# use VBA to color specific words in a list

Tags: excel, vba

SO I have a list of words ( they are 250ish  medications in my Settings sheet ) , and I want to use vba to find those specific words in Column D of another sheet and color them magenta.  Column D has 105 cells that are full of text.

text I want to search:

[image]

list of meds:

[image]

what I want it to look like:

[image]

below is what iv gathered from other resources but I just cant get it to work! please let me know if you have any suggestions!

also it kinda has to work with mac and windows excel

```
   Sub ColorWords3()
  Dim Position As Long, Cell As Range, W As Variant, Words As Variant, Txt As String, druglastcol As Variant, drugs As Variant

  druglastcol = Sheets("Settings").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'Words = Array("TEXT", "WORD", "THEN")
  Words = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Settings").Range("A4:A" & druglastcol).Text)
  For Each Cell In Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    Txt = " " & UCase(Cell.Value) & " "

    For Each W In Words
      Position = InStr(Txt, W)
      Do While Position > 0
        If Mid(Txt, Position - 1, Len(W) + 2) Like "[!A-Z0-9]" & W & "[!A-Z0-9]" Then
          With Cell.Characters(Position - 1, Len(W)).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Color = vbRed
          End With
        End If
        Position = InStr(Position + 1, Txt, W)
      Loop
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Some actual sample data would be helpfull here. *"I can't get it to work"* is just not specific enough. Be clear about **what isn't working**. Show sample data with expected output. Sidenote: `druglastcol` is a very strange name for a variable to count rows.

Comment: You're upper-casing your block of text but not your drug names - `"A" Like "a"` is False.

Comment: hey! I added some picture! id like to just put the sheet on here but I don't really know how.. tbh this is the first time iv had this much trouble and have had to post something

Comment: Your pictures seem to indicate you want to partially-color plural words which contain one of your terms, but your Like pattern doesn't allow for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like is case-sensitive, so you need to upper-case your drug names to match your upper-cased blocks of text.

```
If Mid(Txt, Position - 1, Len(W) + 2) Like "[!A-Z0-9]" & UCase(W) & "[!A-Z0-9]" Then
```

Using `Like` gets a bit clunky so here's a RegExp-based approach:

**EDIT** - added a working Like/InStr version...

```
Sub ColorWords()

    Dim Cell As Range, W, Words, matches As Collection, m

    With Sheets("Settings")
        Words = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("A4"), _
                                      .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))
    End With

    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
        For Each W In Words
            'Set matches = AllMatchesRegEx(Cell.Text, W) 'windows only
            Set matches = AllMatchesInStr(Cell.Text, W)  'windows+mac
            For Each m In matches
                Debug.Print Cell.Address, W, m
                With Cell.Characters(m, Len(W)).Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = vbMagenta
                End With
            Next m
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function AllMatchesInStr(ByVal textToSearch As String, searchTerm)
    Const OUT As String = "[!A-Z0-9]"
    Dim rv As New Collection, pos As Long, start As Long
    Dim next2 As String, next1 As String
    textToSearch = UCase(" " & textToSearch & "  ")
    start = 1
    pos = InStr(start, textToSearch, searchTerm, vbTextCompare)
    Do While pos > 0
        If Mid(textToSearch, pos - 1, 1) Like OUT Then
            next2 = Mid(textToSearch, pos + Len(searchTerm), 2)
            next1 = Left(next2, 1)
            'Handle possible s at end of search term
            If next1 Like OUT Or (next2 Like "S" & OUT) Then
                rv.Add pos - 1
            End If
        End If
        start = pos + 1
        pos = InStr(start, textToSearch, searchTerm, vbTextCompare)
    Loop
    Set AllMatchesInStr = rv
End Function


Function AllMatchesRegEx(textToSearch As String, searchTerm)
    Dim rv As New Collection, matches, m
    Static reg As Object
    If reg Is Nothing Then
        Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        reg.Global = True
        reg.IgnoreCase = True
    End If
    reg.Pattern = "\b" & searchTerm & "s?\b" 'Allow for simple plural form,
                                             'flank with word boundaries
    Set matches = reg.Execute(textToSearch)
    For Each m In matches
        rv.Add m.firstindex + 1 'firstindex is zero-based
    Next m
    Set AllMatchesRegEx = rv
End Function
```

Comment: so, in my list its Amiloride do I need to have it as Amiloride , AMILORIDE or amiloride ? is that what you mean?

Comment: That did it! , thank you! im going to take this and then extend this out to do probably 4 more lists of different things and 4 more colors ! I truly appreciate all of yalls help!

Comment: ok so... I get this Error " ActiveX component cant create object" but its only on my mac. how should I fix that? Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") this is the line it flags

Comment: Sorry that won't work on a Mac - I should have mentioned that.  You can still go back to your previous method...

Comment: well I haven't gotten that method to work :/ im not sure why it wont work either

Comment: It Works! so as I mentioned I planed to expand it for a few more lists , however when I added a list to B4 for hormones ( and I switched the  "Words = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("A4"), _
                                      .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))   " to  Words = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("B4"), _
                                      .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))   ) it ended up importing both the list in A 4 and the list in B4 and threw an error. I solved this by creating a tab for each list, but can you think of a fix so I can keep them on one tab?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code:

```
Words = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Settings").Range("A4:A" & Dr).Text)
```

what is `Dr`?

Also don't do this:

```
druglastcol = Sheets("Settings").Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
```

Do this instead:

```
druglastcol = Sheets("Settings").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The reason we do it this way is the method you have used will stop if there is a blank row in the data, the method i have posted comes from the bottom up so will always grab the true last row.

Comment: sorry ! I changed Dr to druglastcol so the variable name would be more descriptive! but changing it still didn't help

Comment: also when I changed xlDown to xlUp instead of returning the value 258 which is correct it returns 3

Comment: did you remove `4:A` from the range before changing it to xlup?

Comment: no? my list of medication is A4 to A258 but I want to make sure if I add one at the bottom of the list later that it recognizes iv added to the list. did you have any more thoughts on why the coloring wont take?

Comment: Copy and paste my suggestion and for the xlup thing and it will work, your code reads: `druglastcol = Sheets("Settings").Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
` which will give you 3, mine reads: `druglastcol = Sheets("Settings").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
` which will give you the last row of data. I am still working through your code to try and answer your question.

Comment: … I feel a bit dumb with the not removing the 4.... sorry about that

Comment: Nah mate, it's all good, simple mistakes are the easiest to make :). Check Tim's answer, I think that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim s As String
    Dim vDB
    Dim i As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Ws = Sheets("Settings")
    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        setCharacterColor s
    Next i
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub setCharacterColor(strPattern As String)
    Dim mCol As Object 'MatchCollection
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer, Ln As Integer

    Set Ws = Sheets("Facts")
    Set rngDB = Ws.Range("d1", Ws.Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each rng In rngDB
        s = rng.Value
        Set mCol = GetRegEx(s, strPattern)
        If Not mCol Is Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To mCol.Count - 1
                c = mCol.Item(i).FirstIndex + 1
                Ln = mCol.Item(i).Length
                With rng.Characters(c, Ln).Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = vbMagenta
                End With
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetRegEx(StrInput As String, strPattern As String) As Object
    Dim RegEx As Object 'New RegExp
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'New RegExp
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    If RegEx.test(StrInput) Then
        Set GetRegEx = RegEx.Execute(StrInput)
    End If
End Function
```

If your use Mac then try below.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, WsColor As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim vDB, vR
    Dim i As Long, Ln As Integer
    Dim j As Index
    Dim st, et

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    st = Timer
    Set Ws = Sheets("Settings")
    Set WsColor = Sheets("Facts")
    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With WsColor
       Set rngDB = .Range("d1", .Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each rng In rngDB
        For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            Ln = Len(vDB(i, 1)) 'String Length
            vR = getItem(rng, vDB(i, 1)) 'string startedIndex
            If IsArray(vR) And Not IsEmpty(vR) Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(vR)
                    With rng.Characters(vR(j), Ln).Font
                        .Bold = True
                        .Color = vbMagenta
                    End With
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    et = Timer
    Debug.Print et - st
End Sub
Function getItem(rng As Range, v As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vR()
    Dim k As Integer, s As Integer, n As Index
    Dim str As String
    str = rng.Text
    s = 1
    Do
        n = InStr(s, str, v)
        If n > 0 Then
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To k)
            vR(k) = n
        End If
        s = n + Len(v)
        DoEvents
    Loop While n > 0
    If k Then
        getItem = vR
    Else
        getItem = Empty
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for your suggestion! im getting an error " Microsoft Visual Basic Compile error : User-defined type not defined " its referring to line 7 of the mac code Dim j As Index. any suggestions ?

Comment: I replaced As Index with As Variant and it DID color a drug but it was the last drug in the list and all other drugs stayed black!